# Unity Container Registration with Names are not working while without name works fine

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies, containers, unity-container

I know this sounds stupid. I'll provide some pieces of code and will try to explain as much.

#### Implementation #1 - Without name

```
   Container = new UnityContainer();

    Container.RegisterType<IFirstInterface, FirstImplementation>();

    Container.RegisterType<IDifferentAssemblyInterface, DifferentAssemblyImplementation>();
    Container.RegisterType<ISameAssemblyInterface, SameAssemblyImplementation>();
```

#### Implementation #2 - With name

```
const string configurationName = "simpleOption";

Container = new UnityContainer();

        Container.RegisterType<IFirstInterface, FirstImplementation>(configurationName);

        Container.RegisterType<IDifferentAssemblyInterface, DifferentAssemblyImplementation>(configurationName);
        Container.RegisterType<ISameAssemblyInterface, SameAssemblyImplementation>(configurationName);
```

#### Observations

Implementation #1 works just fine. I used the immediate window and everything resolves.

With implementation #2 I used immediate window and everything from the same assembly resolves

Implementation #2 immediate window is not able to resolve exactly the IDifferentAssemblyInterface is not able to resolve

I opened up the Registrations constructor and all the dependencies are

#### Questions

1. Am I using named registration correctly?
2. Is passing the name as simple as that? Just pass a string while registering and the same string during resolve should work.
3. How do I debug/resolve this?

#### Sample Code

Program.cs

```
  static IUnityContainer Container;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Arrange
        Container = new UnityContainer();
        Container.AddExtension(new Diagnostic());


        Container.RegisterType<IMessageReader, ConsoleMessageReader>("Local");
        Container.RegisterType<IMessageWriter, ConsoleMessageWriter>("Local");
        Container.RegisterType<Startup, Startup>("Local");

        Startup startup = Container.Resolve<Startup>("Local");

        // Act
        startup.Run();
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
  public class Startup
    {
        IMessageReader _reader;
        IMessageWriter _writer;

        public Startup(IMessageReader reader, IMessageWriter writer)
        {
            _reader = reader;
            _writer = writer;

        }
        public void Run()
        {
            _writer.WriteMessage(_reader.ReadMessage());
        }
    }
```

Message ReaderWriter

```
public interface IMessageReader
{
    string ReadMessage();
}
public class ConsoleMessageReader : IMessageReader
{
    public string ReadMessage()
    {
        return "Hello, DI";
    }
}

public interface IMessageWriter
{
    void WriteMessage(string message);
}
public class ConsoleMessageWriter : IMessageWriter
{
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", message);
    }
}
```

#### Error Message

```
Unhandled Exception: Unity.ResolutionFailedException: The current type, HelloDIApp.ConsoleClient.IMessageReader, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
_____________________________________________________
Exception occurred while:

·resolving type:  'IMessageReader'
  for parameter:  'reader'
  on constructor:  Startup(IMessageReader reader, IMessageWriter writer)
   resolving type:  'Startup' registered with name: 'Local'
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, HelloDIApp.ConsoleClient.IMessageReader, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? ---> Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException: Exception of type 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Unity.Processors.ConstructorDiagnostic.<>c.<GetResolver>b__11_0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.<OptimizingFactory>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(BuilderContext& context)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.ContextValidatingPlan(BuilderStrategy[] chain, BuilderContext& context)
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(Type type, String name, InternalRegistration registration)
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(Type type, String name)
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(ParameterInfo parameter, Object value)
   at Unity.Processors.ParametersProcessor`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateDiagnosticParameterResolvers>b__0(BuilderContext& context)
   at Unity.Processors.ConstructorDiagnostic.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<GetResolverDelegate>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.<OptimizingFactory>b__0(BuilderContext& c)
   at Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(BuilderContext& context)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.ExecuteValidatingPlan(BuilderContext& context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Unity.UnityContainer.ExecuteValidatingPlan(BuilderContext& context)
   at Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type type, String name, ResolverOverride[] overrides)
   at Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer container, String name, ResolverOverride[] overrides)
   at HelloDIApp.ConsoleClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Code\HelloDI\HelloDIApp\HelloDIApp.ConsoleClient\Program.cs:line 18
```

#### Working Code

When I don't use names it works just fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Arrange
    Container = new UnityContainer();
    Container.AddExtension(new Diagnostic());

    Container.RegisterType<IMessageReader, ConsoleMessageReader>();
    Container.RegisterType<IMessageWriter, ConsoleMessageWriter>();
    Container.RegisterType<Startup, Startup>();

    Startup startup = Container.Resolve<Startup>();

    // Act
    startup.Run();
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to become an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Please show two examples of actual complete (and copy/paste/runnable) code and add the details of what happens in the named case: post all relevant exception details (message, type, and stack trace of the exception and *all* its inner exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to MCVE. There you go. created a little hello world.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way of doing it. I am still looking for answers.

While constructing complex objects we can inform unity about how we want to cherry pick our dependencies. We can play around with all the combinations of different names and create a dependency map. Upon resolving, Unity will go and build exactly as per the order under that name.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Arrange
    Container = new UnityContainer();
    Container.AddExtension(new Diagnostic());


    Container.RegisterType<IMessageReader, ConsoleMessageReader>();
    Container.RegisterType<IMessageWriter, ConsoleMessageWriter>();

    Container.RegisterType<IMessageReader, TwitterMessageReader>("Social");
    Container.RegisterType<IMessageWriter, FacebookMessageWriter>("Social");
    Container.RegisterType<IStartup, Startup>("Social", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IMessageReader>("Social"), new ResolvedParameter<IMessageWriter>("Social")));

    Container.RegisterType<IMessageReader, ConsoleMessageReader>("Local");
    Container.RegisterType<IMessageWriter, ConsoleMessageWriter>("Local");

    var reader = Container.Resolve<IMessageReader>("Social");
    var writer = Container.Resolve<IMessageWriter>();

    Container.RegisterType<IStartup, Startup>("Local", new InjectionConstructor(reader, writer));

    IStartup startup = Container.Resolve<IStartup>("Local");

    // Act
    startup.Run();
}
```